# Can't reloadRowAtIndexPath UItableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have this problem that blow my mind amost 2 months and I still don't know why?
I try to reloadRowAtIndexPath, it work fine, but sometimes, it crashes, reason is "attempt to delete row (x+1) from section (x) which only contains (x+1) rows before the update"

I really need some help, 'cause it doesn't happen always, but just sometimes, i don't know why, on my tester's iphone :(
I have try a lot of way, and here is my code

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
NSNumber *indexNumber = [userInfo valueForKey:@"index"];
int index = [indexNumber intValue];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
[[Settings sharedInstance].saveOdersIndex addObject:indexPath];
@try {
    [listView beginUpdates];
    [listView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [listView endUpdates];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception %@", exception.reason);
    FIRCrashLog(@"Cause Crash button clicked %@", exception.reason);
} @finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");

}
```

Comment: There isn't enough info here to help. 1: are you sure this is the code that is triggering the exception? 2. Provide the code which updates the model and sends the notification with the `index` key.

Comment: where is the your datasource array ?

Comment: This code does not look like it relates to the error message. The error message indicates you are deleting rows but this code only reloads rows. Please add a symbolicated crash log, the real code that causes the error and show which line causes the crash.

Comment: @Dima i sure that this cause the prolem

Comment: @RoboticCat it causes the problem, i not delete any cell at all, i just hide an button in the cell

Answer (score 0):

This error caused due to when `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` was called `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` **returned 0**. You need to insert into the datasource array before you call  -`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

**OR**

Try to replace this line `[listView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` with `[listView reloadData]`;

Comment: I didn't call insertRow ?

Comment: yes but anywhere you have do delete and insert operation for tableview

Comment: Yes, i add row a lot, but now what should i do ?

Comment: then follow my answer.

Comment: can you tell me  line of crash ?

Comment: After reloadRowAtIndex, it crash

Comment: I listening data from sever, so each time we have new, it will auto reload my datasource, so how can i follow your ắner, can you add any exemple

Comment: what should i insert in array ?

Comment: Try to replace this line     [listView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; with [listView reloadData];

Comment: did you call beginUpdates and endUpdates before and after  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation ?

Comment: I solved my problem by remove reloadAtIndexPath, and reload in my custom cell. By the way, thank you for help a lot :Đ

Comment: can i mentioned that in my answer ?

Comment: Sure, you help me to understand exactly why it crashes, and i have to avoid to use it